# how to achieve linux's inotify-tools shell methods on osx

Tags: file, macos, watch, inotify-tools

To monitor a file in linux, I can use inotify-tools like this

```
#!/bin/bash

# with inotify-tools installed, watch for modification of file passed as first param
while inotifywait -e modify $1; do
        # do something here
done
```

but how would I achieve this in OSX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to wrap this into a Python script, you can use Watchdog, which works with both Linux and OSX.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog

Here is what it looks like to replace pyinotify with watchdog:

https://github.com/raphdg/baboon/commit/2c115da63dac16d0fbdc9b45067d0ab0960143ed

Watchdog also has a shell utility called `watchmedo`:

```
watchmedo shell-command \
    --patterns="*.py;*.txt" \
    --recursive \
    --command='echo "${watch_src_path}"' \
    .
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the [FSEvents API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: can this be used in shell script?

Comment: No, but there's a wrapper library for python: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents/0.2.4

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`entr`](http://entrproject.org/) tool. Example usage:

```
ls some_file | entr do_something
```

On Mac install via Brew: `brew install entr`.